# Bitmap error - out of memory

Tags: c#, bitmap, out-of-memory

I try to make an application to generate multiple images by changing the channel order of a picture. I used this code, but I get an error that out of memory when loading images larger than 1500x1500px; For smaller images the code works

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    try
        {
            //Getting The Image From The System
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter =
              "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";

            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Bitmap img = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                pictureBox1.Image = img;

                //get image dimension
                int width = img.Width;
                int height = img.Height;
                //3 bitmap for red green blue image

                Bitmap a01img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a02img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a03img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a04img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a05img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a06img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a07img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a08img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a09img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a10img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a11img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a12img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a13img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a14img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a15img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a16img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a17img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a18img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a19img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a20img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a21img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a22img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a23img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a24img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a25img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a26img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a27img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a28img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a29img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a30img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a31img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a32img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a33img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a34img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a35img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a36img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a37img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a38img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a39img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a40img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a41img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a42img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a43img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a44img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a45img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a46img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a47img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a48img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a49img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a50img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a51img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a52img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a53img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a54img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a55img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a56img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a57img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a58img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a59img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a60img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a61img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a62img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a63img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a64img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a65img = new Bitmap(img);
                Bitmap a66img = new Bitmap(img);



            //red green blue image
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    //get pixel value
                    Color p = img.GetPixel(x, y);

                    //extract ARGB value from p
                    int r = p.R;
                    int g = p.G;
                    int b = p.B;

                    a01img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, r, r));
                    a02img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, r, g));
                    a03img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, r, b));
                    a04img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, g, r));
                    a05img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, g, g));
                    a06img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
                    a07img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, b, r));
                    a08img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, b, g));
                    a09img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, b, b));
                    a10img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, r, r));
                    a11img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, r, g));
                    a12img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, r, b));
                    a13img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, g, r));
                    a14img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, g, g));
                    a15img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, g, b));
                    a16img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, b, r));
                    a17img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, b, g));
                    a18img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, b, b));
                    a19img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, r, r));
                    a20img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, r, g));
                    a21img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, r, b));
                    a22img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, g, r));
                    a23img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, g, g));
                    a24img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, g, b));
                    a25img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, b, r));
                    a26img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, b, g));
                    a27img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, b, b));
                    a28img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));
                    a29img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, g));
                    a30img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, b));
                    a31img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, g, 0));
                    a32img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, g, g));
                    a33img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, g, b));
                    a34img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, b, 0));
                    a35img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, b, g));
                    a36img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, b, b));
                    a37img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, 0, 0));
                    a38img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, 0, g));
                    a39img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, 0, b));
                    a40img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, g, 0));
                    a41img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, b, 0));
                    a42img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, 0, 0));
                    a43img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, 0, g));
                    a44img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, 0, b));
                    a45img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, g, 0));
                    a46img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, g, g));
                    a47img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, b, 0));
                    a48img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, r, 0));
                    a49img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, r, b));
                    a50img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, 0, r));
                    a51img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, 0, 0));
                    a52img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, 0, b));
                    a53img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, b, 0));
                    a54img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, r, r));
                    a55img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, r, 0));
                    a56img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, r, b));
                    a57img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, r));
                    a58img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, b, r));
                    a59img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, r, 0));
                    a60img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(b, 0, r));
                    a61img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, g, 0));
                    a62img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, 0, g));
                    a63img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, r, 0));
                    a64img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(g, 0, r));
                    a65img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, r, g));
                    a66img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, g, r));
                }
            }

            a01img.Save(@".\a01img.jpg");
            a02img.Save(@".\a02img.jpg");
            a03img.Save(@".\a03img.jpg");
            a04img.Save(@".\a04img.jpg");
            a05img.Save(@".\a05img.jpg");
            a06img.Save(@".\a06img.jpg");
            a07img.Save(@".\a07img.jpg");
            a08img.Save(@".\a08img.jpg");
            a09img.Save(@".\a09img.jpg");
            a10img.Save(@".\a10img.jpg");
            a11img.Save(@".\a11img.jpg");
            a12img.Save(@".\a12img.jpg");
            a13img.Save(@".\a13img.jpg");
            a14img.Save(@".\a14img.jpg");
            a15img.Save(@".\a15img.jpg");
            a16img.Save(@".\a16img.jpg");
            a17img.Save(@".\a17img.jpg");
            a18img.Save(@".\a18img.jpg");
            a19img.Save(@".\a19img.jpg");
            a20img.Save(@".\a20img.jpg");
            a21img.Save(@".\a21img.jpg");
            a22img.Save(@".\a22img.jpg");
            a23img.Save(@".\a23img.jpg");
            a24img.Save(@".\a24img.jpg");
            a25img.Save(@".\a25img.jpg");
            a26img.Save(@".\a26img.jpg");
            a27img.Save(@".\a27img.jpg");
            a28img.Save(@".\a28img.jpg");
            a29img.Save(@".\a29img.jpg");
            a30img.Save(@".\a30img.jpg");
            a31img.Save(@".\a31img.jpg");
            a32img.Save(@".\a32img.jpg");
            a33img.Save(@".\a33img.jpg");
            a34img.Save(@".\a34img.jpg");
            a35img.Save(@".\a35img.jpg");
            a36img.Save(@".\a36img.jpg");
            a37img.Save(@".\a37img.jpg");
            a38img.Save(@".\a38img.jpg");
            a39img.Save(@".\a39img.jpg");
            a40img.Save(@".\a40img.jpg");
            a41img.Save(@".\a41img.jpg");
            a42img.Save(@".\a42img.jpg");
            a43img.Save(@".\a43img.jpg");
            a44img.Save(@".\a44img.jpg");
            a45img.Save(@".\a45img.jpg");
            a46img.Save(@".\a46img.jpg");
            a47img.Save(@".\a47img.jpg");
            a48img.Save(@".\a48img.jpg");
            a49img.Save(@".\a49img.jpg");
            a50img.Save(@".\a50img.jpg");
            a51img.Save(@".\a51img.jpg");
            a52img.Save(@".\a52img.jpg");
            a53img.Save(@".\a53img.jpg");
            a54img.Save(@".\a54img.jpg");
            a55img.Save(@".\a55img.jpg");
            a56img.Save(@".\a56img.jpg");
            a57img.Save(@".\a57img.jpg");
            a58img.Save(@".\a58img.jpg");
            a59img.Save(@".\a59img.jpg");
            a60img.Save(@".\a60img.jpg");
            a61img.Save(@".\a61img.jpg");
            a62img.Save(@".\a62img.jpg");
            a63img.Save(@".\a63img.jpg");
            a64img.Save(@".\a64img.jpg");
            a65img.Save(@".\a65img.jpg");
            a66img.Save(@".\a66img.jpg");

           }
                        }



                    catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed loading image");
        }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You really really should be disposing of those bitmaps when done with them, they use up a lot of unmanaged resources. 2) Calling SetPixel inside a loop is very very slow. You need to learn how to use [`Bitmap.LockBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Just create them one at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Image Library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Picasso will make sure there is no out-of-memory error.